# Populate ListBox from SQL only items with condition (first character)

Tags: sql, vb.net, listbox, conditional-statements

I've managed to put all items in a `ListBox`, also have the first character defined `kto`, how to insert only those values from `List` column into `Listbox` that begin with that character `kto`.

Just to mention that `kto` is value from 0 to 9, always a number.

```
        Dim SqlSb As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
    SqlSb.DataSource = ".\sqlexpress"
    SqlSb.InitialCatalog = "Konta"
    SqlSb.IntegratedSecurity = True

    Using SqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(SqlSb.ConnectionString)
        SqlConn.Open()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = SqlConn.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT List FROM Konta"
        Dim kto = Left(Label1.Text, 1)
        'Label3.Text = kto
        Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While (reader.Read())
                Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(reader("LIST"))
            End While

        End Using
        SqlConn.Close()

    End Using
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim SqlSb As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
SqlSb.DataSource = ".\sqlexpress"
SqlSb.InitialCatalog = "Konta"
SqlSb.IntegratedSecurity = True

Using SqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(SqlSb.ConnectionString)
    SqlConn.Open()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = SqlConn.CreateCommand()
    Dim kto = Left(Label1.Text, 1)
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT List FROM Konta WHERE List LIKE '" & kto.toString & "%'"
    ListBox1.Items.Clear
    Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While (reader.Read())
            Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(reader("LIST"))
        End While

    End Using
    SqlConn.Close()

End Using
```

Comment: Thank you. But after first load those values stay there, listbox doesn't reload.

Comment: You can force it using `ListBox1.Refresh()` at the end of the code

Comment: ...Or do you mean that the values ​​loaded the second time are added to the values loaded the first time?. It is obvious then. You are using `ListBox1.Items.Add` without clearing the old values. If so, you can use `ListBox1.Items.Clear` before loading the values

Comment: It's reloading now. Thank you guys a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, before adding the item in the listbox check the date type of reader("LIST") and add it only if matches the required type.

You can check the type using the following code:

```
reader.GetFieldType(0)
```